# c# unboxing via object

Tags: c#, casting, boxing, unboxing

I can cast `byte` to `int` without any problems.

```
byte a = 2;
int b = a;      // => unboxing, boxing or conversion?
```

When I cast `byte` first to `object` and then to `int` I get an `InvalidCastException`.

```
byte a = 2;
object b = a;    // => boxing?
int c = (int) b; // => unboxing fails?
```

But I can workaround this problem by using `Convert.ToInt32`.

```
byte a = 2;
object b = a;                // => boxing?
int c = Convert.ToInt32(b);  // => what happens here?
```

---

- Why do I get an `InvalidCastException` in the second example?
- What does `Convert.ToInt32` in the background?
- Did I label `boxing`, `unboxing` and `conversion` correctly? / What is the correct term when in the examples where I'm not sure?
- Are the conversion operators at play here? Is there an overview about the basic conversion operators of the basic types?

Please don't hesistate to hint me other things I might have gotten wrong or missed.

Comment: In the first case you have an explicit conversion. In the second you are trying to *unbox* a boxed byte using the wrong type. [Convert.ToInt32](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1024) calls the target objet's `IConvertible.ToInt32` method.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for you answer. Makes sense.

Comment: `int c = (byte)b;` seems to work, does this mean you have to unbox with it's original type?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that is not an explicit conversion, there is no explicit cast.

Comment: @SelmanGenç you're right, I was typing while searching the link to Convert.ToInt32 ...

Comment: byte-to-int is a widening conversion, there is no boxing or other plumbing as the conversion will always succeed.

Comment: This tends to surprise VB.NET programmers, a language that permits unboxing to an arbitrary other value type.  Not legal in C#, that was important back in the .NET 1.x days when boxing was very common.  C# is the kind of language that never hides a possible perf problem, deciding for the proper conversion at runtime instead of compile-time is not for free.  The IConvertable interface call cost is substantial compared to the value conversion cost.  If you measure nanoseconds.  By using Convert.ToInt32() you explicitly opt-in for that cost.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the background infos! I allways appreciate it!

Comment: @HansPassant Is casting to IConvertible more costly than unboxing?

Comment: @SelmanGenç You mean boxing to `IConvertible` and then converting? I hope unboxing is not that inperformant?

Comment: Everything is relative.  if the un/boxing conversion lives in the inner loop of a program, like it tended to do in a .NET 1.x program that used collections, and executed many millions of times then, yes, you notice.  Generics in .NET 2.0 solved it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why do I get an `InvalidCastException` in the second example?

Because you specified you want to cast (and at the same time unbox) the type of the (boxed) variable to something else. And there is no built-in, implicit or explicit conversion operator defined, so it fails.

> What does `Convert.ToInt32` in the background?

[This.](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,1024) It uses the `IConvertible` interface to do the conversion.

> Did I label boxing, unboxing and conversion correctly? / What is the correct term when in the examples where I'm not sure?

```
int b = a;      // => conversion
object b = a;    // => boxing
int c = (int) b; // => casting fails
int c = Convert.ToInt32(b);  // => what happens here: a method call that happens to do a conversion
```

> Are the conversion operators at play here? Is there an overview about the basic conversion operators of the basic types?

Yes, although defined in the CLR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @NtFreX, also explicit cast is available if you "unbox" your variable first: `byte b = 42; object box = b; int i = (int)(byte)box`

Comment: @NtFreX you may think that "unboxing" must always be with exactly same type as "boxing", but this technically not true. Take a look at this examples: `int i = 50; object box = i; char ce = (char)(System.PlatformID)box; char cn = (char)(int?)i;`

Answer (score 0):

> Why do I get an InvalidCastException in the second example?

You can unbox in origin type only

> What does Convert.ToInt32 in the background?

It contains a convertation

> Did I label boxing, unboxing and conversion correctly? / What is the correct term when in the examples where I'm not sure?

```
byte a = 2;
int b = a;      // convertation (byte to int)

object b = a;    // boxing
int c = (int) b; //unboxing

object b = a;                // boxing
int c = Convert.ToInt32(b);  // convertation (object to int)
```

> Are the conversion operators at play here? Is there an overview about the basic conversion operators of the basic types?

You can reflect framework code to learn how it works deeper.

Comment: 1. is incorrect for sure: `int i = 50; object o = i; char c = (char)i;`.

Comment: 2. What does that mean?

Comment: 4. That doesn't answer the question really.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Re 1: I can't get this to run, presuming you meant `int i = 50; object o = i; char c = (char)o;`

Comment: @PatrickHofman, also about 1st: `int i = 50; object o = i; char c = (char)(System.PlatformID)o;`

Answer (score -2):

should be

```
object b = a;    // => boxing
int c = (int) b;  //Un-boxing
```